# How to get initial digits from a sum before adding?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation

How would you add digits in such a way that when having a result sum, the initial digits that were added could be extracted/calculated?

For example, when having the following random digits 132748107 the sum of the digits is

```
1 + 3 + 2 + 7 + 4 + 8 + 1 + 0 + 7 = 33
```

How would you get the original list of digits 132748107 from the sum 33?

The result sum does not need to be the correct mathematical sum of the digits. It is allowed the add extra information in the calculations, if that let you extract the initial digits from the resulting number.

Edit: the resulting sum need to be as small as possible.

Edit 2: As @barakmanos wrote in the comments: I am indeed looking for some kind of encoding of the digits into a number, such that one could deterministically decode (extract) them from the resulting "sum".

Comment: `The result sum does not need to be the correct mathematical sum of the digits`??? Then just do $\color\red1\cdot10^8 + \color\red3\cdot10^7 + \color\red2\cdot10^6 + \color\red7\cdot10^5 + \color\red4\cdot10^4 + \color\red8\cdot10^3 + \color\red1\cdot10^2 + \color\red0\cdot10^1 + \color\red7\cdot10^0$. Or in simple words, $132748107$.

Comment: Thanks @barakmanos, although you are correct, I am looking for the smallest possible resulting sum (if that's possible). I've edited my question.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that you've added this requirement. However, if your digits can be anything between $0$ and $9$, then this **IS** the smallest possible result (assuming that you want to be able to decode other cases and not just the one given in your example).

Comment: If your maximal digit is guaranteed to be $8$, then you can use $9$ instead of $10$ in the algorithm that I described on my first comment. If you know that some other digits (e.g., $5$) are never going to be present, then we can devise an even better solution.

Comment: Incomprehensible. You want the smallest number whose digits add up to $33$? That would be $6999$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: To my understanding, OP wants to be able to encode the digits into a number, such that one could deterministically decode (extract) them from the resulting "sum".

Comment: If that's what OP means, @barak, then you ought to set up shop as a professional mindreader.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: I already have. Feel free to pop by (special discount for MSE members).

Comment: @GerryMyerson, sorry if I was not clear, but I am indeed looking for some kind of encoding/compression of a list of numbers where the resulting number is smaller (i.e. take less space) than the original list of digits.

Comment: You may as well look for a perpetual motion machine. There is no compression scheme that works for all numbers and is always able to recover the original number.

Answer (score 0):

You could just count the number of zeroes, ones, ...

E.g., 0+1+1+2+4+9 = 1210100001

However, you get into trouble if there are more than 9 of one digit.